# AWS Lambda is not copying files from one s3 bucket to another in the cloud, but in local it works

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, policy

I want to use a lambda function to copy content from one bucket to another. That is the lambda that I have created:

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var srcBucket = "bkctFrom";
var destBucket = "bkctTo";

module.exports.hello = async event => {  
  var params = {
    Bucket: srcBucket
   };
   await s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    }
    else{
      var cont = data['Contents'];
      var key="";
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(cont)) {
        key = value['Key'];
        s3.copyObject({
          CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + key,
          Bucket: destBucket,
          Key: key
        },
        function (copyErr,copyData){
          if(copyErr){console.log(copyErr);}
          else{console.log(copyData);}
        }
        );
      }
    }
  });
};
```

This fuction works good when I run locally : `sls invoke local  -f hello`, all the content is copyied form the bucket `bkctFrom` to `bkctTo`.

But when I deploy in the aws it doesn't work.  There is no error log, only execution result successed.

[image]
[image]

In local instead of `null` I get the information about the files inserted in the bucket.

This is the policy I am using to create the role for this lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListSourceAndDestinationBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bkctFrom",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bkctTo"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SourceBucketGetObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bkctFrom/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DestinationBucketPutObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bkctTo/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using serverless and that is the `.yml`:

```
service: updaterepobucket
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2


functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
#    events:
#      - http:
#          path: users/create
#          method: get
```

I am refering the role manually in the aws console:
[image]
Here they have another name (only test).

And even if I set full access to S3 it still nt working:
[image]

If it is working from my local but it is not working from the cloud the conclusion is that maybe there are something related to permissions. But I dont know what is missing in this policy. Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

a. Its not clear to me how you're referencing the policy from your `serverless.yml` file. I'd recommend you refer to your policy using the `iamManagedPolicies` section (see https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/ for more details)

b. Either way, the permissions might not be enough. See this AWS Article, "Why can't I copy an object between two Amazon S3 buckets?
": https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-copy-between-buckets/

Hope it helps